# Fail to load class javax.faces.component.MethodBindingValidator when deploy and start JSF web to Geronimo 3.0

Tags: jsf-2, geronimo

I am trying to deploy and start JSF web application using JSF 2.1 with Geronimo 3.0 Server but following error is returned.

```
2014-03-28 11:47:33,478 WARN  [[/oms]] Fail to load class javax.faces.component.MethodBindingValidator interested by ServletContainerInitializer com.sun.faces.config.FacesInitializer
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.component.MethodBindingValidator
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.apache.geronimo.hook.equinox.GeronimoClassLoader.loadClass(GeronimoClassLoader.java:85)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1207)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.GeronimoStandardContext.setContextProperties(GeronimoStandardContext.java:231)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.TomcatContainer.addContext(TomcatContainer.java:299)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.TomcatWebAppContext.doStart(TomcatWebAppContext.java:567)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.createInstance(GBeanInstance.java:1000)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.attemptFullStart(GBeanInstanceState.java:271)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.start(GBeanInstanceState.java:105)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.start(GBeanInstance.java:555)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanDependency.attemptFullStart(GBeanDependency.java:110)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanDependency.addTarget(GBeanDependency.java:145)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanDependency$1.running(GBeanDependency.java:119)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicLifecycleMonitor.fireRunningEvent(BasicLifecycleMonitor.java:176)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicLifecycleMonitor.access$300(BasicLifecycleMonitor.java:45)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicLifecycleMonitor$RawLifecycleBroadcaster.fireRunningEvent(BasicLifecycleMonitor.java:254)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.attemptFullStart(GBeanInstanceState.java:301)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.start(GBeanInstanceState.java:105)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.startRecursive(GBeanInstanceState.java:127)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.startRecursive(GBeanInstance.java:569)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicKernel.startRecursiveGBean(BasicKernel.java:386)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.ConfigurationUtil.startConfigurationGBeans(ConfigurationUtil.java:466)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.KernelConfigurationManager.start(KernelConfigurationManager.java:225)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.SimpleConfigurationManager.startConfiguration(SimpleConfigurationManager.java:710)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.SimpleConfigurationManager.startConfiguration(SimpleConfigurationManager.java:689)
    at org.apache.geronimo.console.configmanager.ConfigManagerPortlet.processAction(ConfigManagerPortlet.java:164)
    at org.apache.pluto.driver.services.container.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:117)
    at org.apache.pluto.driver.services.container.FilterChainImpl.processFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:84)
    at org.apache.pluto.driver.services.container.FilterManagerImpl.processFilter(FilterManagerImpl.java:112)
    at org.apache.pluto.container.driver.PortletServlet.dispatch(PortletServlet.java:359)
    at org.apache.pluto.container.driver.PortletServlet.doGet(PortletServlet.java:261)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:544)
    at org.apache.pluto.driver.container.DefaultPortletInvokerService.invoke(DefaultPortletInvokerService.java:233)
    at org.apache.pluto.driver.container.DefaultPortletInvokerService.action(DefaultPortletInvokerService.java:101)
    at org.apache.pluto.container.impl.PortletContainerImpl.doAction(PortletContainerImpl.java:251)
    at org.apache.pluto.driver.PortalDriverServlet.doGet(PortalDriverServlet.java:135)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.geronimo.console.filter.RedirectByHashFilter.doFilter(RedirectByHashFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.geronimo.console.filter.PlutoURLRebuildFilter.doFilter(PlutoURLRebuildFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.geronimo.console.filter.XSSXSRFFilter.doFilter(XSSXSRFFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.security.SecurityValve.invoke(SecurityValve.java:89)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.security.jacc.JACCSecurityValve.invoke(JACCSecurityValve.java:54)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.GeronimoStandardContext$SystemMethodValve.invoke(GeronimoStandardContext.java:731)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.valve.GeronimoBeforeAfterValve.invoke(GeronimoBeforeAfterValve.java:48)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.valve.ProtectedTargetValve.invoke(ProtectedTargetValve.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at org.apache.geronimo.pool.ThreadPool$1.run(ThreadPool.java:267)
    at org.apache.geronimo.pool.ThreadPool$ContextClassLoaderRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:397)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2014-03-28 11:47:33,601 ERROR [TomcatContainer] Unable to add the child container: /oms .  Please check if your project's context-root is unique.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: addChild:  Child name '/oms' is not unique
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:887)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.TomcatContainer.addContext(TomcatContainer.java:310)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.TomcatWebAppContext.doStart(TomcatWebAppContext.java:567)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.createInstance(GBeanInstance.java:1000)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.attemptFullStart(GBeanInstanceState.java:271)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.start(GBeanInstanceState.java:105)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.start(GBeanInstance.java:555)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanDependency.attemptFullStart(GBeanDependency.java:110)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanDependency.addTarget(GBeanDependency.java:145)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanDependency$1.running(GBeanDependency.java:119)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicLifecycleMonitor.fireRunningEvent(BasicLifecycleMonitor.java:176)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicLifecycleMonitor.access$300(BasicLifecycleMonitor.java:45)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicLifecycleMonitor$RawLifecycleBroadcaster.fireRunningEvent(BasicLifecycleMonitor.java:254)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.attemptFullStart(GBeanInstanceState.java:301)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.start(GBeanInstanceState.java:105)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.startRecursive(GBeanInstanceState.java:127)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.startRecursive(GBeanInstance.java:569)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicKernel.startRecursiveGBean(BasicKernel.java:386)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.ConfigurationUtil.startConfigurationGBeans(ConfigurationUtil.java:466)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.KernelConfigurationManager.start(KernelConfigurationManager.java:225)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.SimpleConfigurationManager.startConfiguration(SimpleConfigurationManager.java:710)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.SimpleConfigurationManager.startConfiguration(SimpleConfigurationManager.java:689)
    at org.apache.geronimo.console.configmanager.ConfigManagerPortlet.processAction(ConfigManagerPortlet.java:164)
    at org.apache.pluto.driver.services.container.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:117)
    at org.apache.pluto.driver.services.container.FilterChainImpl.processFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:84)
    at org.apache.pluto.driver.services.container.FilterManagerImpl.processFilter(FilterManagerImpl.java:112)
    at org.apache.pluto.container.driver.PortletServlet.dispatch(PortletServlet.java:359)
    at org.apache.pluto.container.driver.PortletServlet.doGet(PortletServlet.java:261)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:544)
    at org.apache.pluto.driver.container.DefaultPortletInvokerService.invoke(DefaultPortletInvokerService.java:233)
    at org.apache.pluto.driver.container.DefaultPortletInvokerService.action(DefaultPortletInvokerService.java:101)
    at org.apache.pluto.container.impl.PortletContainerImpl.doAction(PortletContainerImpl.java:251)
    at org.apache.pluto.driver.PortalDriverServlet.doGet(PortalDriverServlet.java:135)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.geronimo.console.filter.RedirectByHashFilter.doFilter(RedirectByHashFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.geronimo.console.filter.PlutoURLRebuildFilter.doFilter(PlutoURLRebuildFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.geronimo.console.filter.XSSXSRFFilter.doFilter(XSSXSRFFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.security.SecurityValve.invoke(SecurityValve.java:89)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.security.jacc.JACCSecurityValve.invoke(JACCSecurityValve.java:54)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.GeronimoStandardContext$SystemMethodValve.invoke(GeronimoStandardContext.java:731)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.valve.GeronimoBeforeAfterValve.invoke(GeronimoBeforeAfterValve.java:48)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.valve.ProtectedTargetValve.invoke(ProtectedTargetValve.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at org.apache.geronimo.pool.ThreadPool$1.run(ThreadPool.java:267)
    at org.apache.geronimo.pool.ThreadPool$ContextClassLoaderRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:397)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:
```

Configuration in web.xml like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">

    <display-name>oms</display-name>
    <!-- SPRING ROOT WEB APPLICATION CONTEXT -->
     <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/config/web-application-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

     <!-- SPRING SECURITY  -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
     <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
   <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- JSF 2 IMPLEMENTATION -->
    <!-- Use JSF view templates saved as *.xhtml, for use with Facelets -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Enables special Facelets debug output during development -->
     <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Production</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- dont reneder comments into output -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
        <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.DisableUnicodeEscaping</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Causes Facelets to refresh templates during development -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
        <param-value>1</param-value>
    </context-param>   
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security Facelets tag library declaration 
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/springsecurity.taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>   -->

   <!-- Just here so the JSF implementation can initialize, *not* used at runtime -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Just here so the JSF implementation can initialize -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.js.resource.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

   <!-- Primes Faces configure -->
   <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.PRIVATE_CAPTCHA_KEY</param-name>
        <param-value>6LfwZwoAAAAAAEhRyntKF1PBzysAJLzqp2v-GMRR</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.PUBLIC_CAPTCHA_KEY</param-name>
        <param-value>6LfwZwoAAAAAAI-oUHpdvRnkMfu9fXQHxc0P7IBu</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>none</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

   <filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>Service Security Token Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>ch.ofwi.oms.filter.ServiceSecurityTokenFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Service Security Token Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>  
    <listener-class>ch.ofwi.oms.listener.OMSSessionListener</listener-class>  
    </listener>  

    <!-- 
    <filter>
        <filter-name>Character Encoding Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.examples.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Character Encoding Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping> -->
    <error-page>
            <error-code>404</error-code>
            <location>/web/error?errorCode=404</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
            <error-code>500</error-code>
            <location>/web/error?errorCode=500</location>
     </error-page>
    <!--   DEFAULT PAGE -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>  
</web-app>
```

Configuration in geronimo-web.xml like bellow

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/j2ee/web-2.0.1"
         xmlns:nam="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/naming-1.2"
         xmlns:sec="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/security-2.0"
         xmlns:sys="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/deployment-1.2">
    <sys:environment>

        <sys:moduleId>
            <sys:groupId>ch.ofwi.oms.web</sys:groupId>
            <sys:artifactId>oms-web</sys:artifactId>
            <sys:version>1.32.2</sys:version>
            <sys:type>car</sys:type>
        </sys:moduleId>

        <sys:dependencies>
        </sys:dependencies>

        <sys:import-package>!org.apache.commons.logging.*</sys:import-package>
        <sys:import-package>!javax.faces</sys:import-package>

        <!--<sys:hidden-classes>
            <sys:filter>javax.faces</sys:filter>
        </sys:hidden-classes>
        <sys:inverse-classloading />-->
    </sys:environment>
    <context-root>/oms</context-root>
</web-app>
```

Any help would be appreciated!